# Initialize a dictionary with non-optional empty arrays in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type

I'm trying to associate an array numerical data with a column label, so I thought I'd model that with a dictionary that maps a string to an array of floats. I'm trying to populate the dictionary by initializing the key values with empty arrays, but I keep getting optional arrays instead. Here is an example,

```
var labels = [ "pine", "elm", "palm" ]
var dframe = [String:[Float]]()
for label in labels {
    dframe[label] = [Float]()
}
print(dframe.dynamicType) // --> Dictionary<String, Array<Float>> 
print(dframe["pine"].dynamicType) // --> Optional<Array<Float>>
```

I confused about why the initialization `[Float]()` in the for-loop produces an optional array. If I say `[Float]()!` in the for-loop, then I get an error saying that I *"cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[Float]'"*. Any ideas? I just want a simple, non-optional mapping of strings to arrays of floats. I'm using XCode 7.1.1, and Swift 2.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access a dictionary with:

```
let x = dframe["pine"]
```

The compiler didn't know if you pass a valid key to the dictionary, if you didn't, it will return nil. The optional part is not in the array initialization, but in the value search of the dictionary.

Comment: That makes sense now, thanks! I knew there had to be a reasonable explanation for that behavior.